# Glitch with linear layout inside gridview when in landscape orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I am having difficulty with a layout glitch.  I have a different layout for portrait and landscape.  **The problem only appears on the landscape layout** even though the xml in both is the same.

[This image shows the problem](http://www.eaglelakewoodworking.com/pics/androidlayout.png)

The problem occurs inside of a GridView row.  In the row, I have these controls:
 
TextView1 ImageButton1 TextView2 Textview3 EditText ImageButton2 Imagebutton3

I am using layout weight to have the TextView2, TextView3 & EditText controls occupy the remaining space.

The different between the portrait layout and landscape layout is this:
The portrait layout is a vertical stack of 4 different sections.  The landscape is a split with two of the section on the left side of the screen and two on the right.

Here's the code for the GridView row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gridfield_MemoryOrdinalPosition"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ff6e807c"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></TextView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnGoMemoryPosition"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@mipmap/go_arrow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gridfield_MemoryLiftPosition"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0.00"
            style="@style/MemoryLiftPositionStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gridfield_MemoryLiftPositionUnits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ff2d2eff"
            android:text="in"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/gridfield_MemoryName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_text_edit"
            android:text="Named location"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSetMemoryPosition"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/save"
        android:contentDescription="Save" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnClearMemoryPosition"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/trash"
        android:contentDescription="Delete" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `activity_horizontal_margin` might be different in landscape.
by default it is 16dp in portrait and 64dp in landscape.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I am new to Android, and never would have thought that a margin value would be different depending on the orientation.  Now I know to look out for this.  I spent way to long trying other things and should have asked sooner, but I am very grateful for your quick and accurate reply.